# How to get information from xrp rippled like data api v2 in localhost

Tags: api, tags, cryptocurrency, xrp, rippled

I run rippled service in my own server. Its state is now 'full' :

```
$ /opt/ripple/bin/rippled server_info | grep state
2020-Feb-12 11:02:16.279916836 HTTPClient:NFO Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5005

         "server_state" : "full",
         "server_state_duration_us" : "4721798525",
         "state_accounting" : {
```

I want to check depoists to a XRP address with a destination tag. I find a public api for this purpose :
"https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts/rhEN3yNym2mk5QFJnnHkqvUus7SD3KAyFD/payments?destination_tag=627053"
But I want to use this in my server's rippled service?
How can I do this?

Thank you in advance